# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS multiple graphics glitches on old computer

Tags: graphics, keyboard, display, gpu-driver

I have a thinkpad X220T and ever since I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 18, then 19 and now 20.04 LTS I have been having multiple weird problems with graphics. Some of them are:

1. Text in multiple places (time on the taskbar, on application title bars and application menus for example) turns to either boxes or some font that is unreadable (not english). This happens occassionally.
2. If I am using an application like a terminal emulator, with maybe vim or even something else running in it, sometimes there is a line or or a cursor shaped box that starts flashing containing the display data of some other application like a browser running in the background. Taking a screenshot is difficult because as soon as I press the screenshot key the problem dissappears. I can also type `alt + f2`and then `r` and this also temporarily fixes the problem, but it typically returns if I keep using the computer.
3. The screen starts tearing randomly.
4. Just right now when I was logging into to Stackexchange I typed my email, then pressed backspace a few times to correct some typos in my email. The characters that I had just deleted start flashing ahead of where my cursor was.

As you can imagine, these problems are very frustrating. They typically start after the computer has been running for a while, or if I lock the screen and unlock after a few hours. I am using an external monitor with the laptop lid closed. I don't think these problems are due to my old video card malfunctioning, as they started after an upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 about a year ago, and my windows dual boot does not show similar problems. If there is a stress test to check the health of the graphics card then I would request for it. I am using gdm3, I briefly switched to Ubuntu Cinnamon in between and these problems were reduced but not completely eliminated.